# adding a menu tab?

Tags: css, xhtml, dotnetnuke

I am making a top menu, and it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O5G5.png

The contact tab will remain in its place and the home tab has to be first.

IF the user wants to add another tab, they can in the cms editior (DNN) they would just create the link and wrap the div tag about the link etc..

im stuck to how i can get the css to add the menu tab and push the home tab to the left as the menu grows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sounds like you are trying to manually build the menu using HTML. What you need to do is ensure that you have the DNN navigation control as part of your skin and it will handle adding the menu items for you. You'll be able to modify the menu to look however you like using CSS.

The best way to learn DNN skinning is to look at one of the existing skins (found in /Portals/_default/skins/) and then copy one of the skins and start making changes to change it to your desired look.

The DNN skinning architecture is very well done and easy to pick up for anyone who knows ASP.NET (though it is different from Master Pages). The hardest part is picking and learning to work with the various navigation providers. Most people work with DNNMenu which is more complicated than it needs to be on the CSS Side. The DDR Menu which will be the default provider for DNN 6+ should be easier to work with. But the documentation for it isn't complete yet so it takes some learning to get started with it.